# Websocket vs stocking session scoped bean

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websocket

I have to notify clients of new entries in my database. Naturally I think about websocket to have a two waypoints communication. In an EJB I keep a list of all the `javax.websocket.Session` and then I do `session.getBasicRemote().sendText("new notifcation");` for each of them. But I was wondering, instead of using websockets, why not stock all the current session scoped beans in a daemon (like a `@Singleton` EJB) and then notify all these beans ? Then the beans would notify their client using something like

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("console.log('new notification")`

Comment: Well, I guess I know the solution, We can initialize a javascript execution on client form server only if it's after a request from client. So in my case, I want to intialize the request from server, then this kind of stuff RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("console.log('new notification") do not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can initialize a javascript execution on client form server only if it's after a request from client. So in my case, I want to intialize the request from server, then this kind of stuff RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("console.log('new notification") do not works